# Why $P(\theta, y \mid x) = P(\theta \mid x, y)P(y \mid x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Can any one give me any intuation like I'm 10 years old... why below is legal?

The definition of conditional probability states that the joint probability of two events $A$ and $B$ can be expressed as the product of the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ and the probability of $B$: $$P(A, B) = P(A \mid B)P(B)$$

- Thus $A=\theta$ and $B=y \mid x$, why $P(\theta \mid y \mid x) = P(\theta \mid x,y)$????

In step 2, we apply this definition to the joint probability $P(\theta, y \mid x)$ in two different ways. First, we can treat $\theta$ as event $A$ and $y$ as event $B$, giving us: $$P(\theta, y \mid x) = P(\theta \mid x, y)P(y \mid x)$$

Alternatively, we can treat $y$ as event $A$ and $\theta$ as event $B$, giving us: $$P(\theta, y \mid x) = P(y \mid x, \theta)P(\theta \mid x)$$

- And how this one is come out?

Both of these expressions are valid ways to apply the definition of conditional probability to the joint probability $P(\theta, y \mid x)$.

Comment: $B$ is not $y\mid x$.  There is no such event as "$y\mid x$".  There's your first problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrange $A\cap B\cap C$ in two ways to see that:

$$(A\cap B)\cap C = A \cap (B\cap C)$$

---

Using the conditional probability definition you cite and treating $A\cap B$ as the first event and $C$ as the second event we see that

$$\Pr((A\cap B)\cap C) = \Pr(A\cap B\mid C)\Pr(C)$$

Now, do this again but this time with $A$ as the first event and $B\cap C$ as the second event but keep going and expand the resulting $\Pr(B\cap C)$ as well.

$$\Pr(A\cap (B\cap C)) = \Pr(A\mid B\cap C)\Pr(B\cap C) = \Pr(A\mid B\cap C)\Pr(B\mid C)\Pr(C)$$

Divide both expressions by $\Pr(C)$ and recall that they are equal.  We have as a result:

$$\Pr(A\cap B\mid C) = \Pr(A\mid B\cap C)\Pr(B\mid C)$$

or, using the variable names you chose, replace $A$ with $\theta$, replace $B$ with $y$ and $C$ with $x$.

Comment: +1 Nice, May be  you can add the proof for conditional density following such rule also. that would be interesting.

Comment: Thanks. Made more sense by your logic prove, but still not so intuition(like a venn graph) for me...